# Remove specific stopwords Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, stop-words

New to Pyspark, I'd like to remove some french stopwords from pyspark column.
Due to some constraint, I can't use NLTK/Spacy, `StopWordsRemover` is the only option that I got.

Below is what I have tried so far without success

```
from pyspark.ml import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import *

stop = ['EARL ', 'EIRL ', 'EURL ', 'SARL ', 'SA ', 'SAS ', 'SASU ', 'SCI ', 'SCM ', 'SCP ']
stop = [l.lower() for l in stop]
    
model = Pipeline(stages = [
        Tokenizer(inputCol = "name", outputCol="token"), 
        StopWordsRemover(inputCol="token", outputCol="stop", stopWords = stop),]).fit(df)
    
  result = model.transform(df)
```

Here is the expected output

```text
|name          |stop          |
|2A            |2A            |
|AZEJADE       |AZEJADE       |
|MONAZTESANTOS |MONAZTESANTOS |
|SCI SANTOS    |SANTOS        |
|SA FCB        |FCB           |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have trailing spaces in your stop words. Also, you don't need to lowercase them unless you need the [`StopWordsRemover`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover.html) to be case sensitive. By default it is set to false, you can change that using the parameter `caseSensitive`.

Note that when you are using `Tokenizer` the output will be in lowercase. If you need the output with the same case as input column `name`, then it might be preferable to simply [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) the column `name` by white spaces.

Try with this:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

stop = ['EARL', 'EIRL', 'EURL', 'SARL', 'SA', 'SAS', 'SASU', 'SCI', 'SCM', 'SCP']
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2A",), ("AZEJADE",), ("MONAZTESANTOS",), ("SCI SANTOS",), ("SA FCB",)], ["name"])

df = df.withColumn("tokens", F.split("name", "\\s+"))
remover = StopWordsRemover(stopWords=stop, inputCol="tokens", outputCol="stop")

result = remover.transform(df).select("name", F.array_join("stop", " ").alias("stop"))

result.show()
#+-------------+-------------+
#|         name|         stop|
#+-------------+-------------+
#|           2A|           2A|
#|      AZEJADE|      AZEJADE|
#|MONAZTESANTOS|MONAZTESANTOS|
#|   SCI SANTOS|       SANTOS|
#|       SA FCB|          FCB|
#+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Stopwords from dataframe, I tried Join and Filter approach: -

1. Dataframe Left : WordCound output in form of dataframe
2. Dataframe Right : Stopwords in a single column
3. Left Join on the required 'text' columns
4. Filter out the records where there is a match in joined columns
5. *(Used lowercase in both dataframes)*

`word_df = clean_df \
            .withColumn('words',explode(split(col('course_title'), ' ')) )\
            .withColumn('lowerCaseWords', lower(col("words")) ) \
            .groupBy('lowerCaseWords')\
            .count()

stopwords_df = spark \
                .read \
                .option("header",False) \
                .csv("/FileStore/tables/standard/stopwords.csv") \
                .withColumn("stopword", lower(col("_c0")) )

join_word_df = word_df \
                    .join(stopwords_df,word_df["lowerCaseWords"] == stopwords_df["stopword"],"left")

final_wordcount_df  = join_word_df\
                        .filter(col("stopword").isNull()) \
                        .filter(length(col("lowerCaseWords")) != 1 ) \
                        .filter(length(col("lowerCaseWords")) != 0) \
                        .drop("stopword","_c0") \
                        .orderBy(col("count").desc()) \
                        .display()`